# ASP.Net Page Sometimes Freezing Before Page Loads

Tags: asp.net

I have a pretty standard ASP.Net page written in C#. Most of the time it loads just fine and works a treat but occasionally the page won't load, I've inserted break points in the Page_PreInit (I don't actually have any code here, I've just created the function so I can see if the codes getting this far) but it's not getting this far. Any ideas where I should start in looking for a solution?

Comment: The problem only seems to occur in IE, it's almost like the page can't be found

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to help you debug

- Turn on tracing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we%28VS.71%29.aspx
- It may be throwing an exception you aren't seeing (although I would expect it to give you the YSOD...). Debug the application and turn on "Break when an exception is thrown" for Common Language Runtime Exceptions (hit CTRL+ALT+E to bring up the options)

When the page doesn't load, what happens? Does it never finish loading, do you get an error message?

Comment: The page just doesn't load. If you hover the mouse over the page you get the vista loading icon but it never gets any further. This is in the output: "The thread 0x19a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0)."